# How to solve heap space error?

Tags: android, eclipse, memory

I have develop android application using Android SDK, Eclipse IDE.In that some times showing heap space error and close eclipse.what is heap space?hw to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to increase `-Xms` and `-Xmx` in the `eclipse.ini` file, and restart eclipse.

Comment: look for the eclipse.ini file, open it and look for what I ve already said

Answer (score 0):

Heap is a part of the memory (RAM) where program stores the variables.

Your problem, maybe, could be the allocation of variables in a thread or in a cicle.

For example:

```
while(....) {
    Object o = new Object();
    .....
}
```

Comment: hw to identify this type of declaration?

Comment: local variable doesnt get store in heap memory. only objects will be there in heap memory. local variable resides on the stack

Comment: Android you're right! I wanted to write an example with object declaration, my fault!

Answer (score 0):

try disabling the lint, but remember he is doing exceptionally important, then after editing your xml reactivate.

> window> preferences> lint error checking> uncheck the checkbox two

Try also monitor the status of the heap>

> window> preferences> general> show heap status